# How to view SELinux config file

Tags: centos, selinux

**OS**: CentOS 7.4.1708

I'm testing SELinux but I can't figure out how to open the config file to view it.  I'm sure this is simple but nothing seems to work.  How do I do this?

**Attempt 1)** I navigated to `/etc/sysconfig` but I can't navigate further into the `/selinux` folder.  This folder is cyan colored which indicates that it is a symbolic link.  I'm not sure what to do in that case.

**Attempt 2)** I typed `cat /selinux/config` but received the error

`cat: /selinux/config: No such file or directory`

I'm not trying to edit the config file.  I just want to look inside to learn about the settings inside of it.

**--update--**

My Nginx reverse proxy wouldn't work until I entered this into the command line,

`httpd_can_network_connect true`

I'm trying to look at the config or related files to see/understand what I did to make my reverse proxy work.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see the domain, file context, etc. definitions?

Comment: `httpd_can_network_connect true` I used this command to make a reverse proxy server work and I'm trying to figure out what I did by looking at the config or related file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SELinux policy source is in the `selinux-policy` SRPM. Once you have downloaded, installed, and patch-built it you will need to look under `serefpolicy-x.y.z/policy/modules/contrib/apache.*` to find all the httpd-related rules and booleans and then follow the rabbit down the hole from there.